# flip horizontaly (X) a ParticleEffect [Libgdx]

Tags: java, libgdx, particles

i got a particle effect thats is inside a group

```
 shellParticle = new ParticleEffect();
    shellParticle.load(Gdx.files.internal("shell13"),Gdx.files.internal(""));
    shellParticle.getEmitters().first().setPosition(0,0);
    shellParticle.scaleEffect(0.3f);
```

i need it to flip horizontaly but it just have the function `flipY` and `setFlip(bool X, bool Y)`

```
setFlip(true,false)
```

just do nothing.  flipY() actualy flip it verticaly.
Also i cant substract its own width*2 beause it dosent have so please help me

Comment: Why are you doing `shellParticle.getEmitters().first().setPosition(0,0);` instead of `shellParticle.setPosition(0,0)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a lack of infrmation from part of libgx api.
The `setFlip` method is flipping the particle sprites (for particles which have already been emitted and future particles).
`flipY()` modify propieties of emmiter setting everithing to negative
but setting to negative just some of properties i get the `flipX()` method.
Acctualy every change you wanna do with particules you shoud do it with emmiters properties exeptiong for the x and y position.

```
   private void flipX(){


    emmiter.getAngle().setHigh(emmiter.getAngle().getHighMin(),emmiter.getAngle().getHighMax());
    emmiter.getAngle().setLow(emmiter.getAngle().getLowMin(),emmiter.getAngle().getLowMax());

    emmiter.getGravity().setHigh(emmiter.getGravity().getHighMin(),emmiter.getGravity().getHighMax());
    emmiter.getGravity().setLow(emmiter.getGravity().getLowMin(),emmiter.getGravity().getLowMax());

    emmiter.getWind().setHigh(-emmiter.getWind().getHighMin(),-emmiter.getWind().getHighMax());
    emmiter.getWind().setLow(-emmiter.getWind().getLowMin(),-emmiter.getWind().getLowMax());

    emmiter.getRotation().setHigh(-emmiter.getRotation().getHighMin(),-emmiter.getRotation().getHighMax());
    emmiter.getRotation().setLow(-emmiter.getRotation().getLowMin(),-emmiter.getRotation().getLowMax());

    emmiter.getYOffsetValue().setLow(emmiter.getYOffsetValue().getLowMin(),emmiter.getYOffsetValue().getLowMax());

    emmiter.getXOffsetValue().setLow(emmiter.getXOffsetValue().getLowMin(),emmiter.getXOffsetValue().getLowMax());

}
```

I hope it helps someone.